# How can I pass command-line arguments containing special characters to a process launched via Perl or Bash?

Tags: perl, command-line, curl

I need to launch curl for a test. I need to send XML which has " /  and other crazy things. Whats the quickest way to do it? I tried

```
curl -k -d '<xs:element name="Login"/>' https://thewebsite.com/page.exe
```

with no luck.

Comment: You really, really should read the SOAP::Lite documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash escape it.

```
\"
```

Comment: hmm, i tried in a batch file with no luck. I didnt think bash would allow it. It echos properly.

Comment: brian d foy: in  batch file. I didnt think to try on a bash. It does work in bash

Answer (score 3):

In Perl, use the list form of [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

```
system curl 
    => qw(-k -d '<xs:element name="Login"/>' https://thewebsite.com/page.exe);
```

Or, better yet, use [WWW::Curl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Curl#WWW::Curl::Easy) (see also the [libcurl documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html)).

Answer (score 2):

The use of 'qw' to quote parameters given in one of the answers here is not correct, qw will explictly escape and pass the single quotes around the xs tag, where as in the OP's example, they wouldn't

You could use...

```
system('curl', '-k', '-d', '<xs:element name="Login"/>', 
       'https://thewebsite.com/page.exe');
```

Which should be what you're after. I'd try to use the module though.